# errno: 150 "Foreign key constraint is incorrectly formed" Can someone edit this?

Tags: mysql

Hello I am new to all this could someone explain and edit why I am getting error on creating this?

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `gangs_grade` (
  `gradeId` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `gangId` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `grade` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
  `name` varchar(65) DEFAULT NULL,
  `salary` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
  `maleSkin` text DEFAULT NULL,
  `femaleSkin` text DEFAULT NULL,
  `accessVehicle` tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT 1,
  `accessArmory` tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT 1,
  PRIMARY KEY (`gradeId`),
  KEY `gangId` (`gangId`),
  CONSTRAINT `gangs_grade_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`gangId`) REFERENCES `gangs` (`id`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=7 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

#1005 - Can't create table `test`.`gangs_grade` (errno: 150 "Foreign key constraint is incorrectly formed")

What is wrong here?

Comment: Provide complete CREATE TABLE script for `gangs` table.

Comment: Swap the order of declaring `gangs` and `gangs_grade`.